# Slack Events API / RTM: New app installed realtime notification

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to get a slack event or real time message indicating that a new app was installed in a workspace? I can figure out apps which use "bot users" by listening for team_join event. But how can i find out in near realtime about apps installed that don't have a bot user. My use case is to present something to the user when a new app is installed (as soon as possible. I can find out apps from team logs but thats not realtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing with the `team_join` event is basically all you can do. And that's going to rely on either the app having a bot user, or it being a workspace app (https://api.slack.com/slack-apps-preview), which creates an app user.

Other than that, nothing is exposed in the Events API around app installation. The other alternative is to connect up via the RTM API and watch for the `bot_added` and `commands_changed` events. That *should* catch most apps.